# Extending function parameter types with intersection type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to use intersection types to extend a function that has already an incomplete definition.

With this code :

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use("/route", (req:IncomingMessage, res:ServerResponse)=>{
   //do stuff with req and res
})
```

I'm using a connect middleware `body-parser` which is adding a `body` field to the `req` Object so it's not anymore just an `IncomingMessage` but an `IncomingMessage` with a `body` field.

I have tried to define an intersection type like this

```
interface bodyContent = {
   body : {
      foo : string
      }

type intersectionType = bodyContent & IncomingMessage;
```

and rewriting my binding like this :

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use("/route", (req:intersectionType, res:ServerResponse)=>{
   //do stuff with req.body and res
})
```

But Typescript is still complaining that the callback provided has the wrong format since `use` is not defined like this.
How do i *extend* the existing official definition of this software without modifying it.

Thank you.

Edit: 
Since it has been asked, here is use type definition :

```
use(route: string, fn: HandleFunction)
```

HandleFunction definition :

```
type handleFunction = (req: IncomingMessage, res: http.ServerResponse) => void;
```

Comment: How *is* `use` defined - what is its type signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `any` type like so

`WebApp.connectHandlers.use("/route", (req: any, res: ServerResponse)=>{
   //do stuff with req and res
})`

and typescript wouldn't complain anymore, but you probably don't want that, because using `any` is terrible.

Here's a better solution:

`WebApp.connectHandlers.use("/route", (req: IncomingMessage, res: ServerResponse)=>{
  const reqWithBody = req as intersectionType;
  //do stuff with reqWithBody and res
})`

This also feels like a hack, but I don't see a better way out of this situation, since you don't want to change the library's source code and you're dependent on them, and they haven't taken this situation into account.